# Apply currency formatting to Y Axis

Tags: reactjs, data-visualization

I am using the React-Vis library (https://uber.github.io/react-vis/documentation/general-principles/scales-and-data) to create a line chart. I was able to set `XType={'time'}` on my `<XYPLot/>` component to get time values on the X Axis.

However I'm having trouble changing my number values on the Y axis to appear as currency values. I just need a $ sign in front of the number. Anyone know how to do it?

My render() code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ChartContainer>
          <h2>{this.state.chartTitle}</h2>
          <FlexibleXYPlot
            xType="time"
          >
            <HorizontalGridLines />
            <VerticalGridLines />
            <LineSeries data={this.state.chartData}/>
            <XAxis title={this.state.XAxisLabel} position='middle' tickSize={2} />
            <YAxis title={this.state.YAxisLabel} position='middle' tickValues={[]} />
          </FlexibleXYPlot>
        </ChartContainer>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Accomplished by setting the `tickFormat` prop on the target axis:

```
<YAxis
  title={this.state.YAxisLabel}
  position='middle'
  tickFormat={v => `$${v}`}
/>
```